# Fixed table footer

Tags: objective-c

tableFooterView of a UITableView scrolls with the table, can I make it stay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the footer as a separate UIView (or whatever) under the table. You don't have to override UITableView at all.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if your tableView only has a single section, you could return that view as the `-tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`.